# Error while writing data from Linux server to SQL Server using dbWriteTable

Tags: r, sql-server, linux, odbc

I'm trying to write data to a table in SQL Server using `dbWriteTable` from `odbc` package. And, getting this error:

```
dbWriteTable(con1, 'mtcars', mtcars[1:5, ])
```

> Error:  'CREATE TABLE "mtcars" ( "row_names" varchar(255), "mpg" FLOAT, "cyl" "disp" FLOAT, "hp" FLOAT, "drat" FLOAT, "wt" FLOAT, "qsec" FLOAT, "vs" FLOAT, "am" FLOAT, "gear" FLOAT, "carb" FLOAT)' nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'mtcars'.

It's working fine from a windows machine. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) option is OFF for that session.  Probably because of the FreeTDS driver.

> The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver and SQL Server Native Client
>   OLE DB Provider for SQL Server automatically set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to
>   ON when connecting. This can be configured in ODBC data sources, in
>   ODBC connection attributes, or OLE DB connection properties. The
>   default for SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF for connections from
>   DB-Library applications.

You can try setting QUOTED_IDENTIFER ON, or switch to the [Microsoft ODBC Driver for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I tried `sqlExecute(con1, 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON')` before `dbWriteTable`, still didn't work..

Comment: That was just an example

Comment: Thanks so much @David Browne - Microsoft. Problem got solved..